# numpyで効率的に行列を作りたい

Tags: python, numpy

ある整数Nを与えたら、以下のようなN×N-1の行列Zを出力するようなプログラムを書きたいです。

```
Z = [[1 2 3 ... N]
     [0 2 3 ... N]
     [0 1 3 ... N]
      ...
     [0 1 2 ... N]
     [0 1 2 ... N-1]]
```

つまり、i番目の行は、iを除くすべての値を持っているような行列です。単純なコードを書くと

```
Z = [[j for j in range(N) if j != i] for i in range(N)]
```

となるのですが、Nが大きくなると時間がかかってしまいます。

このようなことを、numpyで効率的に書くにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 参考までに、`Z = [range(0,i) + range(i+1,N) for i in range(N)]` とした場合、`N=10000` で 3.79秒 -> 1.14秒になりました(`timeit`で計測)。

Comment: numpyでちゃんと書くと Z = [np.concatenate((np.arange(0, i), np.arange(i+1, N))) for i in range(N)] ですかね？ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか。for文は使わないようにしてみました。

```
import numpy as np

N = 4
Z = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=int)
Z += np.arange(N)
Z = Z[np.eye(N, N) == 0].reshape(N, N - 1)
```

Comment: 一行にして `Z = np.tile(np.arange(N), (N, 1))[np.eye(N, N) == 0].reshape(N, N - 1)`, timeit で計測したところ(`N=10000`)、740 ms でした。速いですね。

Comment: 私のコードはちょっと冗長でしたね。別解としてはこうもかけそうです `np.arange(N).reshape(1, N).repeat(N, 0)[np.eye(N, N) == 0].reshape(N, N - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

timeit (N=10000) で計測すると、mjyさんの回答を、以下のように`np.zeros`から`np.empty`に変更するのが一番早くなりました。260msぐらいで、他の回答より2倍以上早いです。今回のケースでは結果が全部置き換えられるので`np.empty`を使って初期化しなくても問題ありません。

```
def by_np_slice2(N):
    nums = np.arange(0, N, dtype=np.int)
    result = np.empty((N, N-1), dtype=np.int)

    for i, a in enumerate(result):
        a[:i] = nums[:i]
        a[i:] = nums[i+1:]

    return result
```

また、コメントにある`np.arange`を使って`for`で繰り返し処理をする方法も360msぐらいで悪くはありません。`for`の繰り返しで`result[i]`とnumpyの`array`をインデックスで扱う処理が遅いので、`numba`を入れてJITコンパイルすると速くなります。230msぐらいで処理できるようになり上の処理よりも少し早くなりました。

```
@numba.jit
def by_np_arange(N):
  result = np.empty((N, N-1),dtype=np.int)
  for i in range(N):
    result[i] = np.concatenate((np.arange(0,i), np.arange(i+1,N)))
  return result
```

for文を使わない方法だと以下の単位3角行列を使うのが単純で速いのですが390msぐらいです。for文を使うなというのが常識ですが、場合によるようです。

```
Z = -np.tri(N, N-1, -1, dtype=np.int)
Z += np.arange(1,N)
```

Comment: 今の `by_np_arange` だと `a` は捨てているので、`result` は `np.empty` で確保した状態のままです。
これで正しい結果が出たとすると、おそらく `np.empty` で前回の計算結果が残っているメモリ領域が割り当てられたのでしょう。

Comment: 確かにそうです。元に戻しておきます。

Answer (score 2):

スライスを使う例です。
`for` ループを少しでも速くするために、ループ内で使う変数のスコープを出来るだけ小さくしています（つまり小さな関数の中に入れています）。

```
def by_np_slice():
    nums = np.arange(0, N, dtype=np.int)
    result = np.zeros([N, N-1], dtype=np.int)

    for i, a in enumerate(result):
        a[:i] = nums[:i]
        a[i:] = nums[i+1:]

    return result
```

---

質問の出力例、 
`Z = [[1 2 3 ... N]   中略 [0 1 2 ... N-1]]` は、
`Z = [[1 2 3 ... N-1] 中略 [0 1 2 ... N-2]]` 
が正しいのかなと思い、上はそのつもりで書いてあります。

Answer (score 2):

こっちのほうがちょっとだけ速そう

```
mask = np.tile([False] + [True] * N, N)
x = np.tile(np.arange(N), N)
x = x[mask[:N*N]].reshape(N, N-1)
```